# web api odata with v3 filters any all not working with entity framework.

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to use the new filters 'any' and 'all' with odata and entityframework.

For ex: I want to find out the employees who has dotnet skills. 
so I have a skill model class with name as one of the property and employee model class which has a collection of skills. Now when I query(odata) employees with filter Skills/any(skill: skill/Name eq 'Dotnet') , I have to get all the employees who has Dotnet in the skill collections.

But when I apply the filter entity framework is throwing an exception saying that collection is not supported. But if I execute the query without applying filters and then apply the filters to the result list it works.
Please help.

Comment: Does the same error get thrown with any `$filter` option, or is it only any/all that are causing problems? Could you include the exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: stack trace and original exception message would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be Skills/any(skill: Name eq 'Dotnet') ? So without the skill/ near Name.

Comment: It appears the original is correct... http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2012/04/21/odata-v3-anyall-support/

Comment: it works when i updated to entity framework 5, i was using ef4